# How do I take input/output from a form and store it in a JS variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating the UI of a web app, and haven't done any back-end work yet.

For testing purposes, I want my forms to be able to work, so I want to take the input they have received and store it in javascript variables so I can access them, using jQuery.

Everything I have looked at, tells me how to pass js variables into the form, not the other way around.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var variable = $('#myInput').val()`. Or if your form is submitting using `GET`, you may want to look at [the jQuery URL Parsing](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/url_parser) plugin to get access to the variables on the new page.

---

**Edit:**

Sample form (should be a simple text box):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="#">
            <input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

With that form you can use the above sample code. Incidentally, you can use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method on any jQuery selector that returns form elements, e.g. `$('input:text').val()` will get you the value of all text input fields (as an array if there are multiple values).

Comment: Where #myInput is what? The name of the form, the element in the 'action' attribute of the form? Or the name of the 'input' that has the submit button?

Comment: In this example, `myInput` is the id of the input element, hence the id selector `#`.

Comment: Could you provide a code example of what the form might look like?

Thanks.

P.S. Not trying to be a pain, but I tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Almost there.....I am trying to view the info in the variable with this code:
 var comment_box = $("<form action='#'><input id='comment' type='text' name='comment'></form>").appendTo(tag_box).css({"position":"absolute"});
   
   var input_var = $('#comment').val();
   console.log(input_var);

But for whatever reason, it won't output to the console of both Google Chrome on Mac or Firefox (Firebug) on Mac.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're code is exactly what you've shown, you're loading the value of your input before anything is in the input field, i.e. $('#comment').val() is always ''. Try adding the code to a submit handler for your form, e.g. $('form').submit(function() { var input = $('#comment').val(); console.log('Form value: ' + input); });

Comment: console.log wasn't working...for whatever reason...in that code example above, so I changed it to produce an alert, and that works. I can now see the value stored in that variable.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this pretty awesome question on how to [serialize a form to JSON with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery) which would be a good start.

You can also take a look at the [jQuery Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin which provides the **formSerialize** method that

> Serializes the form into a query string. This method will return a string in the format: name1=value1&name2=value2

as well as a **fieldSerialize** method which

> Serializes field elements into a query string. This is handy when you need to serialize only part of a form. This method will return a string in the format: name1=value1&name2=value2